# cycling randomly through animations on button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation

I have an app that currently rotates a button (image) twice when pressed. I'm wanting to cycle through scaling the button and also shaking the button. So the three animations would be: Scale, translate, rotate. How can I cycle through these randomly? Here's what I currently have for the button:

```
- (IBAction)playAudioAction:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;

    CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
    fullRotation.duration = 0.5;
    fullRotation.repeatCount = 2;
    [btn.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];

    [self playAudioOfType:btn.tag];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply a random animation to the button you can have an array of `CABasicAnimation`s and randomly pick one of them.

Somewhere initialize and configure the animations and add them to an array (I'd make it a property).

```
CABasicAnimation * fullRotation = ...
CABasicAnimation * scale = ...
CABasicAnimation * translate = ...
self.animations = @[ fullRotation, scale, translate ];
```

Then when you randomly pick one, remove all the previous ones and add the new one.

```
- (IBAction)playAudioAction:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;

    NSInteger randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(self.animations.count);
    CABasicAnimation *randomAnimation = self.animations[randomIndex];
    [btn.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [btn.layer addAnimation:randomAnimation forKey:@"animation"];

    [self playAudioOfType:btn.tag];

}
```